# JavaScript/jQuery finding string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have a table with some data in it, and I want to look for a specific string within `tbody`, I have got this logic:

`if ($('.table--cart tbody tr td')) { ... }`

Within the table I check if there is a string `str` within that td.

`if ($('.table--cart tbody tr td')[0].innerHTML.indexOf(str) !== -1)){ ... }`

But it doesn't work as expected, when I search in my dev tools for `table--cart`,it returns `not found`, but the first check passes,resulting in an error `undefined is not an object, evaluating $('.table--cart tbody tr td')[0].innerHTML.indexOf(str) !== -1`.

Is my first check wrong? I only want to execute the second check when the first one is true, obviously.

Comment: You might want to use `:contains()` for this issue.
https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: try using $('.table--cart tbody tr td').first().has(str) also the `$` should come before `('.table--cart ...`

Comment: You use jQuery to get your element, but jQuery doesn't have a method `innerHTML`, you can try `html` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first check is incorrect.

```
$('.table--cart tbody tr td')
```

This will return the jquery prototype. You need to do either:

```
if ($('.table--cart tbody tr td')[0])
```

or

```
if ($('.table--cart tbody tr td').length != 0)
```

The reason is, a jquery selector like so:

```
$('#I-dont-exist')
```

Will still return the jquery prototype, such that you can still call things like parent() on a jquery object whose selector found 0 elements. If you change it to either of the ways I listed above, the first check should be correct. I think your indexOf(str) does not do what you expect, however.

EDIT: 
Also I think your evaluation should be:

```
if ( $('.table--cart tbody tr td')[0].html().indexOf(str) !== -1 )
```

Comment: I believe that length is not a function ;-)